# How to create get method inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

I am searching how to combine many code inside a javascript file.

For example, I have 2 codes inside this js:

```
 First: --> code is for timer function,   
 Second: -> for login action.
```

I need the *First* code this time, so I can write it like :

```
 <script src="javascript.js?action=timer"></script>
```

But I don't know how to do with `GET` method in js. It's very easy in PHP, but I don't know the method in JS. What can I do next? Thanks for helping....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a poor way to approach what you want, one of the better methods being something like:

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<script>Application.init("timer");</script>
```

But you could do something like this in PHP:

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>

var action = <?php echo $_GET["action"]; ?>;
console.log(action);
```

With the embed code:

```
<script src="javascript.php?action=timer"></script>
                       ^^^^ Note we're looking at a PHP file.
```

If you're determined to have the `.js?` extension, you can create a rewrite rule to accommodate that.

Comment: what about js? is it also can be implemented?

Comment: @user2285311 There is no JavaScript method to access GET data - is that what you're asking?

Comment: If I use RewriteRule, I should write what? Sorry, If I always asking. I just beginner in Regex and Apache Conf File.

Comment: @user2285311 I personally wouldn't go through the effort just to change `.php` to `.js`. It's not going to benefit anyone.

Comment: @user2285311 If you *must* then it would be something like `RewriteRule ^javascript\.js(.+)$ javascript.php$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do like this
just import the js in your page and call the appropriate function.

Comment: I want to know how it can be like <script src="jquery.js?version=1.0.2">. If I change to 1.11.0, the code become 1.11.0 version. I mean like that.

Comment: You cant do like this,create a directory for jquery and change its content to newer version wherever you wish to.

Other wise point to cdns of different versions

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create new functions inside the same file?  In that case, you can simply use the standard `function` keyword.

If you are trying to auto-run a function when you load the script, I'd have to ask *why?*  It is normal to manually run the function when you need it -- sometime after the `script` is loaded.

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
timer();  // invoke the function
```

Comment: I want to know how it can be like <script src="jquery.js?version=1.0.2">. If I change to 1.11.0, the code become 1.11.0 version. I mean like that.

Comment: Yes, you can do that... but it risks having caching problems on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Those GET parameters are not available in your JavaScript. You can separate the files into two distinct ones (quite easy) or you can process things on the server side so the correct stuff is returned (unnecessarily complicated). If you just want to pass in more parameters on load, try putting the code from those files into a function and then calling the function with some arguments when the page loads.

Comment: Oh... Thanks.. Can you give some examples from your explanation...?